# Uploading multiple files in single multipart post

Tags: android, spring, spring-mvc, multipartform-data

I'm trying to figure out how to go about uploading multiple files to my server in one post request. Based off [this](http://www.journaldev.com/2573/spring-mvc-file-upload-example-tutorial-single-and-multiple-files) example, here's what I've come up with so far:

```
private HttpResponse multiPartPost(File file, String mime, Bitmap thumbnail) throws IOException {

    MultipartEntityBuilder builder = MultipartEntityBuilder.create();
    builder.setMode(HttpMultipartMode.BROWSER_COMPATIBLE);
    builder.addBinaryBody("file", file, ContentType.create(mime), audioName);

    if (thumbnail != null) {
        ByteArrayOutputStream os = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        thumbnail.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, os);
        builder.addBinaryBody("file", os.toByteArray());
        os.close();
    }
    builder.addTextBody("workId", workId);

    HttpPost post = new HttpPost(myURL);
    post.setEntity(builder.build());

    return new DefaultHttpClient().execute(post);
}
```

My controller:

```
@ResponseBody
public void saveMediaDetails(@RequestParam(value="file") MultipartFile[] files,
                             @RequestParam(value="workId") int workId,
                             HttpServletRequest request,
                             HttpServletResponse response) {
    // Stuff
}
```

Problem is `files[1]` is always empty and I only ever receive the first binary body. I've put a breakpoint within the `(thumbnail != null)` block and it does get reached. Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Adding content type and filename to the second binary body fixed the problem.

```
builder.addBinaryBody("file", os.toByteArray(), ContentType.create("image/jpeg"), null);
```